# Synonyms for black eye without the word "eye"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a synonym like that? Example sentence:

> One Monday, Mary showed up with a __ at work.

Comment: So, essentially you are looking for a synonym for eye?

Comment: @thomj1332 I edited the example. Could be anything that means black/bruised eye (hopefully not too formal/scientific).

Comment: Related: [Why is a black eye called a “shiner”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89551/why-is-a-black-eye-called-a-shiner)

Comment: What is the context? What is wrong with _black eye_?

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: "hopefully not too formal/scientific."  So that's a 'no' for *periorbital hematoma*?

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A [**shiner**](https://www.google.com/amp/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm=shiner&amp=true): ***bruised or blackened eye***

Example from [mirror.co.uk](http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/boxing/my-little-lad-loves-shiner-10331470):

> 'My little lad loves my shiner' reveals Anthony Joshua after Klitschko win that secured him £15million payday

Also, 2001 movie named: [Shiner](https://www.google.com/search?&q=shiner%20from%20boxing).

> Michael Caine stars as Billy "Shiner" Simpson, a small time *boxing* promoter with big ideas.

**Sources:**

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shiner)

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shiner)

Comment: Wow, that's an _eye-opener_ (pun intended); I wouldn't have imagined _shiner_ meaning _this_ earlier. Not sure how many would take it for a _black eye_ in `Mary showed up with a shiner at work`. +1.

Comment: Bold. Be bold and bold the **answer**. An example sentence taken from the net, or its etymology would make this answer sweeter.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thx Mari. I updated everything.

Comment: I noticed, great work! If you don't mind, I'm leaving the comment above so new users can see that it is relatively easy to write good complete answers that are also supported. Reams and reams of pages is not necessary on a SWR.

Comment: No problem at all. ;)